# AngularJS datagrid paging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datagrid, pagination

I am using [this angularjs datagrid](http://www.angularcode.com/angularjs-datagrid-paging-sorting-filter-using-php-and-mysql/) .I am facing problem with pagination, this grid shows all pages in pagination for example if i have 500 record and i want to show 10 record per page it will create pagination 1 to 50 but i want like this way 
First«1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.... » Last .That means according to  records the pagination will be shown if the records are too large then the pagination should display with dots(.....).Can anybody give me any hint showing where to change to obtain the above feature ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example uses an angular-ui bootstrap directive for pagination. See all available settings for [pagination](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination). Set the max-size attribute to your desired number of visible buttons and you are good to go.

```
<pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
```

Comment: Able to set the max-size but still didn't able to configure the dot(..) options!Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: Try and reference the latest bootstrap-ui and see if that fixes the problem. ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js) and bootstrap.css (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css)